# How to use exec_query or exec_update with MySQL and PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am trying to use prepare statement query for MySQL and PostgreSQL

Following code works for PostgreSQL

```
connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
query = 'UPDATE stores SET key = $1 WHERE id = $2'
connection.exec_query(query, "SQL", [[nil, 'x'], [nil, 1]])
```

But When I switch the database and the query to following

```
query = 'UPDATE stores SET key = (?) WHERE id = (?)'
connection.exec_query(query, "SQL", [[nil, 'x'], [nil, 1]])
```

Getting following error

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?) WHERE id = (?)' at line 1: 'UPDATE stores SET key = (?) WHERE id = (?)'

Gem versions:

```
gem 'mysql2', '0.4.5'
gem 'pg', '0.18.2'
gem 'rails', '5.1.4'
```

How can I use prepare statement which will work for both MySQL & PostgreSQL with ActiveRecord?

Comment: Why are there brackets on the update statement? does `UPDATE stores SET key = ? WHERE id = ?` work?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try like this

```
exec_query('your query', name = 'SQL', binds = [[nil, 'x'], [nil, 1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL you can use [raw_connection](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/AbstractAdapter.html#method-i-raw_connection) to prepare the statement and then execute the statement:

```
st = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection.prepare(
       'UPDATE users SET slug = ? WHERE id = ?'
     )
st.execute(username.parameterize, id)
st.close
```